# how can i create rest api with swagger and firebase as an SGBD in xamarin.forms

Tags: asp.net, firebase, xamarin.forms, swagger

i'm creating a xamarin.forms application so i'm using mvvm pattern and firebase as an SGBD, then i added a new application web ASP.NET core to the project and i implemented swagger to build some REST API . but i'm confused about how to do that:
should i recreate the models folder in the new application ?
how to insert the firebase connection in the new application?
informations: dotnet's version:4.8.04084 , xamarin.forms version: 5.0.0.2337 ,visual studio 2022

Comment: if you want to share models between two apps, you can create a library project that both apps reference

Comment: and I assume using Firebase in a ASP.NET project is the same as using it in Xamarin - install the client nuget, etc